# Laravel row update, Request method

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, request, query-builder

I am trying to update a row in my database using this function in `VehicleController`, but I get no data prefilled in input fields:

```
public function editVehicle(Request $request, Vehicle $vehicle, Customer $customer)
    {

        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                    'plate' => 'required', //plate is primary key <VARCHAR>
                    'cust_id' => 'required',  //cust_id is foreign key <INTEGER>
                    'type' => 'required',
                    'brand' => 'required',
                    'year' => 'required',
                    'mileage' => 'required'
            ]);

            $this->vehiclesService->editVehicle($request, $vehicle);

            return redirect()->route('Customers:detail', ['customer' => $customer]);
        }

        return view('vehicles.form', ['vehicle' => $vehicle]);

    }
```

Then I have `VehiclesService` model with this function:

```
public function editVehicle($request, $vehicle)
    {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $vehicle) {

            $vehicle->cust_id = $request->cust_id;
            $vehicle->type = $request->type;
            $vehicle->brand = $request->brand;
            $vehicle->year = $request->year;
            $vehicle->mileage = $request->mileage;
            $vehicle->plate= $request->plate;

            DB::update('update vehicles set cust_id=?, type=?, brand=?, year=?, mileage=? where plate=?', 
                    [$vehicle->cust_id, $vehicle->type, $vehicle->brand, $vehicle->year, $vehicle->mileage, $vehicle->plate]);

            Log::info('Vehicle updated.');

            flash('Vehicle successfully updated', 'success');
        });

    }
```

And my form for editing the vehicle (for example just one input field) looks like this:

```
<label>Plate number</label>
<input type="text" value="@if(isset($vehicle)){{$vehicle->plate}} @endif" name="plate" id="plate" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter plate number, eg. 'PP123KL'">
```

Function which creates a vehicle works fine. When I create a vehicle, I am using customer `id` (from table `customers`) which is assigned to `cust_id`(from table `vehicles`) so the vehicle belongs to the given customer. This way, `cust_id` is foreign key.

I have a similar function for customers (edit customer) which doesnt have any foreign keys and it's private key is `id`, type `serial integer` and this function works perfect. But in vehicles, I am using `plate`, type `varchar` as private key what makes me think that Postgresql might have a problem with, since it's not called `id` so and this functions doesn't work. Form is not prefilled and also even if I try to input some data into input fields and Save edit, data is not saved - vehicle was not edited at all.

Either way, I spent hours trying to fix it and get my editing form prefilled with data from database for given vehicle, but no luck at all.

**UPDATE:**

Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/vehicles'], function () {
        Route::match(['get'],   '/{plate}/edit', 'Vehicles\VehicleController@edit')->name('Vehicles:edit');
        Route::match(['post'],  '/{plate}/editVehicle', 'Vehicles\VehicleController@editVehicle')->name('Vehicles:editVehicle');
}};
```

VehicleController:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id) {
        $vehicle = Vehicle::with(['customer'])->find($id);
        return view('edit', compact('vehicle'));
    }

public function editVehicle(Request $request, Vehicle $vehicle)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                    'plate' => 'required',
                    'cust_id' => 'required',
                    'type' => 'required',
                    'brand' => 'required',
                    'year' => 'required',
                    'mileage' => 'required'
            ]);

            $this->vehiclesService->editVehicle($request, $vehicle);

            return redirect()->route('Customers:detail', ['customer' => $vehicle->customer]);
        }

        return view('vehicles.form', ['vehicle' => $vehicle]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue lies with your edit vehicle function in your controller.

What url are you using to select the vehicle to be edited? Your controller is expecting a full vehicle object AND a full customer object. It's not really going to be possible to pass them on a GET request.

You really should have a separate controller for your GET:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id) {
  $vehicle = Vehicle::with(['customer'])->find($id);
  return view('edit', compact('vehicle'));
}
```

Then you'll have a proper model in your view. Set up your view so that it uses the model. Then update your existing route for editing as you'll now have a model to pass into that controller.

You won't need to pass in Customer as a second parameter either. When you have done saving the vehicle, you can use $vehicle->customer for your redirect.

Also not sure why you are using the DB statement to save. Just use $vehicle->save();

Comment: I am using url `http://localhost:8000/vehicles/KK134IL/editVehicle` where `KK134IL` is plate number

Comment: I have updated my question with the code you provided but it is giving me an error `Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column vehicles.id does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "vehicles" where "vehicles"."id" = $1 limit 1` ..what is that `id` for? Is it customers `id`?